# How to cut 5th field in unix with pipe delimitor and how to find minimum date value from that field

Tags: unix, sorting, awk, cut

I have file, in that file 5th filed is date field . I want cut that field and find minimum value in that field.

Pl help me.

my date format is as follows:

```
05142013
05132013
05152013
```

Comment: some sample data wouldn't hurt

Comment: How is your date field formatted?

Answer (score 2):

`cut` is always good for cutting (obvious). So, `cut -f5` can make it.

Regarding the minimum date, you can use `sort`. As you have the format like MMDDYYYY, to sort it based on the date you can do:

```
sort -k1.5,8                    -k1.1,2                 -k1.3,4            file
      year (5th to 8th chars)    month (first 2 chars)   day (3rd and 4th chars)
```

So all together should be

```
sort -k1.5,8 -k1,2 -k1.3,4 <(cut -f5 file)
```

#### Test

```
$ cat file
hello my name is 05142013
bye my name is 05132013
hello blabla name is 07132013
hello my name bloooo 02192013
hello you name is 05152013
hello my blabla is 05152012
$ sort -k1.5,8 -k1,2 -k1.3,4 <(cut -d" " -f5 file)
05152012
02192013
05132013
05142013
05152013
07132013
```

#### Update

As [commented by devnull](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/17345181/how-to-cut-5th-field-in-unix-with-pipe-delimitor-and-how-to-find-minimum-date-va/17345206?noredirect=1#comment25172097_17345206), it suffices with `k1.5,8`, as `MMDD` is the rest of the text to be sorted and there is no need to specify an un-default order.

```
sort -k1.5,8 <(cut -f5 file)
```

Comment: Kind of, @JS웃, haha! I was with Radiohead but I guess I was unconsciously influenced by mr Eminem :)

Comment: I'm sure that I'm missing something here, but it seems that `-k1,2 -k1.3,4` is redundant.

Comment: Mmm check what you just wrote, my code has the `k1.something`

Comment: Oh, yes.  That's what was implied.  `-k1.5,8` would suffice, wouldn't it?  This is what I was trying to figure.

Comment: Oh @devnull, you are absolutely right. As the rest of the string is `MMDD`, which is the other we want, there is no need to force it with more `-k1.XXX` like I did. So `-k1.5,8` completely suffices. Thanks!!

Answer (score 1):

This would work if you wish to do entirely with `GNU awk`.

```
awk  ' 
match($5,/(..)(..)(....)/,ldate) {
    ndate = mktime (ldate[3]" "ldate[1]" "ldate[2]" "0" "0" "0);
    fdate = (NR>1 && fdate < ndate) ? fdate : ndate
}
END {
print strftime("%d%m%Y",fdate)
}' FS="|" inputFile
```